# simple functions crashing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I built a function and it is an endless cycle of errors: the shell never stops running until you kill it manually.  The function is:

```
def f1(x):
    return f1(x)
```

My question is, what causes the function to behave this way?

Comment: It is a recursive function with no base condition at which point it should stop.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not the sort of question a professional or enthusiast programmer would ask.

Comment: You are calling the function recursively and you never set any condition to get out of the function

Comment: What are you expecting to happen with this code?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr go for it bud.  Im brand new to python, meaning your assumption about me being a professional is utterly wrong

Comment: There's a "solution" to the errors. Before the function, type import sys; sys.setrecursionlimit(50000) . The crash will be much nicer then.

Answer (score 2):

This function is calling itself. So, you call fl then f1 returns f1. That f1 gets another f1 and that goes on forever. Although I am not sure about the error you are getting, could you provide the error messages.

Comment: It's a traceback error, nothing to worry about though because I figured out that python stops looping after 1000 loops

Comment: The (user adjustable) recursion limit was added to prevent out-of-memory errors, which are harder to recover from, because there may not even be enough memory left to construct the out-of-memory error traceback.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the function in the function, thus creating what is known as infinite recursion.

Comment: are there any values that won't make it crash?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by values. The bottom line is, don't call a function inside of itself unless there is a condition to stop the recursion.